# How to make ajax requests with images in Yii

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'am trying to make AJAX request and response with images in Yii and I don't know even where to start. I managed to display images from images folder using db requests for file names. I want to make it so when I click on one image it sends requests to the server and it updates my div with another pictures with comes out from db.

What I got is Controller:

```
$modelCars = EeCarTypes::model()->findAll();
        $this->render('index',array(
            'model'=>$modelCars,
        ));
```

And view:

```
$uploadUrl = Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true) . '/images/upload/cartypes/';

foreach( $model as $key => $item )
{
    $imgName = $model[$key]->attributes['car_type'];
    $imgID = $model[$key]->attributes['id'];
    $imgFullUrl = $uploadUrl . $imgName;
    echo "<a href=\"$imgID\"><img src=\"$imgFullUrl\" alt=\"$imgName\"></a>";
}
```

I tried to find some widget that would do it for me but I coudnt find one. I would appriciate some tips, links, ideas.
Thanks you guys a lot.

Comment: The line     echo "<a href=\"$imgID\"><img src=\"$imgFullUrl\" alt=\"$imgName\"></a>" is not going to cut it. Figure out how to do it without Yii first, then change your view to include this code.

Comment: In order to make the picture change without reloading the page, you are going to have to use some javascript (Ajax) as you said. So something like this, click on the image, it calls a javascript function which uses Ajax to request the new image path from a PHP page (the PHP page could contact the DB if you need it to). Now javascript has the new image path, then you can use javascript to replace the html of the image tag with the new image path.

Answer (score 0):

Index view:

```
    <script>
    $('.image').click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            data: {primaryKey: "keyImage"}
            success: function (data) {
                $('#imageContainer').html(data);
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
 function actionIndex()
    {
        if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest && Yii::app()->request->getQuery('primaryKey')) {
            $model = EeCarTypes::model()->findByPk($_GET['primaryKey']);
            echo $this->renderPartial('/view/..', ['model' => $model]);
            Yii::app()->end();

        }
        $this->render('index');
    }
```

View for renderPartial:
 get $model and print image